# Parsing usernames/links in a tweet in Rails and twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I've got a Rails app in which I'm building an interface for a user to send a tweet with text, a link, and/or an image. I'm trying to figure out how to handle parsing links into a `t.co` format and what to do with usernames, but I'm coming up short on any clear explanation of what's required.

I'm using the `twitter` and `omniauth-twitter` gems and I've also found the `twitter-text` gem. What I need to know is, am I required to parse links into a `t.co` format or do anything to usernames in my app before posting to the API? If so, how can I do that in Ruby/Rails? The documentation for the `twitter-text` gem, which seems to be the official way to handle this function, is nonexistent.

Thanks!

Comment: the t.co shortening will be automatic... just post a normal link.  It will affect your character count. see https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update and  https://dev.twitter.com/overview/t.co

Comment: So do I need to detect if a link is present and then subtract that from the remaining character count? I'm pretty sure I would need to do that, but am wondering what the best way would be to do it. I could use a regexp, but that would be problematic with non-fully qualified urls (that don't start with http:// or https://).

Comment: My understanding of the `twitter-text` gem is that it's a library designed to do all that for you.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right, the twitter-text does do that for you. You don't need to parse links. If you're not delaying the submission of tweets you could just go ahead and submit the user input regardless of character count, and then display any error(s) back to the user.  In any case, to make your question more meaningful post the code that you've tried, and what has or hasn't worked, and you'll get more directed answers.

Comment: So before I was just calling `auto_link(text)` and getting a NoMethod error, but I just realized I need to prefix it with `Twitter::Autolink` to generate html with links from the tweet or `Twitter::Extractor.extract_urls(text)``to get an array of urls. Just answered my own question.

Comment: Cool.  If you think your answer will help others who might be struggling, you can post an answer to your own question.